# str.join returning different value for a list and set

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, join, set

I have a list of characters which looks as below:

```
str1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I am performing `join` on `str1`

```
str2 = ''.join(str1)  
print(str2)
```

**Output:** `abc`

Now, I have a set of characters which looks as below:

```
str3 = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

I am performing `join` on `str3`

```
str4 = ''.join(str3)  
print(str4)
```

**Output:** `cba`

I understand that order is not preserved in a `set`. In that case, I should be getting a random
value of `str4` every time when I execute the code. However, I am always getting `cba` as the output.

Why I am getting the output `cba` when using `str.join` with a `set`?

Comment: 'Order is not preserved' at most implies 'arbitrary order', not 'uniformly random' order.

Comment: "I understand that order is not preserved in a set. In that case, I should be getting a random value of str4 every time when I execute the code" no, the latter is not implied by the former at all.

Comment: A Python `set` stores things in a hash table.  A given string always has the same hash, so  the order of a given set of strings should always be the same.  It just isn't predictable in advance.

Comment: "In that case, I should be getting a random value of str4 every time" What do you mean by "random value [..] every time" exactly? What is your justification for this sentence? There isn't any.